# Run PHP Script in C# winforms

Tags: c#, php, mysql, winforms, call

I'm implementing a C# application with combination of PHP script to synchronize my localhost mysql database with remote server. I did implement a PHP script to synchronize two database tables. but, I'm looking for a solution to call my PHP script in C#. Right now, I'm using below PHP code to synchronize my local DB with remote host:

```
<?php
include "sync.php";

$sync = new SyncronizeDB();
//masterSet(dbserver,user,password,db,table,index)
$sync->masterSet("localhost","root","","database1","table1","index_id");
//serverSet(dbserver,user,password,db,table,index)  
$sync->slaveSet("localhost","root","","database2","table2","index_id");
//syncronizing the slave table with the master table (at row level)
$sync->slaveSyncronization()
?>
```

I want to run this script in my C# application. So that, I can synchronize my database within a certain time.

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks in Advanced!

Comment: @CodeCaster What I need is to synchronize my database from remote server. I don't use PHP CLI for the application. is there any solution for call above php file in C# application?

Comment: You can run it with php.exe, or make a webrequest to a server that runs php and hosts this file, or you can convert the code to C#. You can't run php files directly from a .NET application.